# How do I crash Ant's <input> task?

Tags: ant, continuous-integration, bamboo

We run Bamboo CI Server.

There are a number of misconfigured plans (who don't correctly inherit the build.xml from the template project in our version control, or who don't set -D properties correctly according to our internal standards) that will trigger an Ant's `input` task.

While my template project prevents inputs by detecting whether we are running or not in Bamboo, this is not developer-fail-proof.

#### I would like to ask if there is any way to either crash Ant, or redirect the stdin to `/dev/null` at Bamboo instance level.

Currently, plans stuck at inputs will simply wait indefinitely until the main plan timeout rings, which could be a great idea to reduce.

Comment: I have such an idea... modify Ant wrapper inside the CI server environment to make it always " < /dev/null". Scary

Comment: Honest answer, you shouldn't be running scripts designed for user input on CI. At the very least, write your scripts to only prompt for input when the relevant properties are not set, so you can set them in your automation server and not have to worry. Create separate input dependency tasks that have `if="property"` in their target elements.